# $(this) in another function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't understand why I cannot pass $(this) into another function for some reason. I am not sure If I am missing something to my structure ?

Shouldn't this hide my div .myclass ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('.myclass').length) {
    init($(this));

    function init(test) {
        test.hide();
    }

  }
});
```

Comment: What is the problem?  What do you think `this` is?

Comment: why do you think $(this) should be bound to `.myclass` HTML Element?

Comment: You are misunderstanding this and jQuery. this is the element when you use methods like each. But in this case you are not using a jQuery method. The this is going to be `this === document`

Comment: @SLaks and @mehulmpt it makes sense for one to think that `this` is the `.my-class` since that's what is in the if statement. However, `this` couldn't be `.my-class` since we are getting the length, so `this` would be the document from my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this)` in your code refers to `document` which cannot be hidden.
I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but if you want to hide `'.myclass'` objects, you can use the code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('.myclass').length > 0) {
    init($('.myclass'));
    //init($(this)); //This is document

    function init(test) {
        test.hide();
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='myclass'>Hi</div>
```

Comment: In jQuery, if you use a particular search result multiple times, it's better to set the jQuery object to a variable and use the var, rather than recreating the jQuery object.  `let myClass = $('.myclass');`, then use the `myClass` var

Comment: It should be noted that in a .on("click", function() { $(this) will represent the object clicked vs $(document).